# Debugging - See what events are being triggered on an iPad

Tags: javascript, debugging, ipad, dom-events

Does anyone know if there is a way to see what JS Events are being triggered on an iPad?

I have tried connect the iPad to a Mac and using the Safari Developer tools but they do not seem to show this.  (or I am missing something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS Events can be shown under "Timelines" in the Safari developer tools (console). This should work, when correctly connected for remote debugging on an ipad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'monitorEvents' function from within the Developer tools API.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html